# Array: How to put value in array index?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have text boxes with a default value. I want to put them in array output as shown below.

P.S: I need the expected array output (shown below) for my dynamic options in my online quiz program when creating questions

```
  if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])
  {
    //code here
  }

<form method="post">
  //question 1 array index [0]
  <input type="text" name="option" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="option" value="2">
  <input type="text" name="option" value="3">

  //question 2 array index [1]
  <input type="text" name="option" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="option" value="2">

  <input type="submit" name="btn_submit">
</form>
```

**EXPECTED ARRAY OUTPUT VALUES:**

```
array ( 
    [0] => 1,2,3 
    [1] => 1,2   
)
```

**EDIT:**

It's possible to have the same name but still gets the expected array value? then, put them in one variable array

Comment: *It's possible to have the same name but still gets the expected array value?* u need to use different name if you want to store in different indexes.

Comment: or use like `option[0][]` and for second one `option[1][]` with one more index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use array in name attribute as:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="option_1[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="option_1[]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="option_1[]" value="3">

<input type="text" name="option_2[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="option_2[]" value="2">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{
    $newArr[] = implode(',',$_POST['option_1']);
    $newArr[] = implode(',',$_POST['option_2']);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($newArr);
}
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,2,3
    [1] => 1,2
)
```

---

If you just want to use one single name `option` than use this:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="option[0][]" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="option[0][]" value="2">
  <input type="text" name="option[0][]" value="3">

  <input type="text" name="option[1][]" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="option[1][]" value="2">

  <input type="submit" name="btn_submit">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{
  $newArr[] = implode(',',$_POST['option'][0]);
  $newArr[] = implode(',',$_POST['option'][1]);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($newArr);
}
```

Comment: name="option[]" -- can i use the same name in all text boxes but stil get the expected array output?

Comment: @VanAdrianCabrera: answer udpated

Comment: i don't want to implode it. I just want to put it in one variable array then im done. how?

Comment: @VanAdrianCabrera: your expected result is: Array
(
    [0] => 1,2,3
    [1] => 1,2
)

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with following code and IT WILL WORK.

```
 if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])
  {
    //code here
  }

<form method="post">
  //question 1 array index [0]
  <input type="text" name="option[0][]" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="option[0][]" value="2">
  <input type="text" name="option[0][]" value="3">

  //question 2 array index [1]
  <input type="text" name="option[1][]" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="option[1][]" value="2">

  <input type="submit" name="btn_submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `[]` before the option name to make it as an array.

```
//question 1 array index [0]
<input type="text" name="option_1[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="option_1[]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="option_1[]" value="3">

//question 2 array index [1]
<input type="text" name="option_2[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="option_2[]" value="2">
```